# Estoy intentando instalar un certificado SSL local a mi pagina

Tags: ssl, certificado-ssl

Ya lo he instalado en el dominio con la herramienta puTTY pero estoy intentando incorporar mailgun y pues para que funcione necesito el certificado SSL tambien en local, estoy siguiendo este tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mb8OkCLS43w y pues me da un error, esto es lo que tengo en mi virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName panetown.com
  ServerAlias panetown.com
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/shopp-app/public"
  # Por aqui la ruta absoluta donde se aloja tu web para futuras renovaciones en Let's Encrypt
    Alias /.well-known "C:/wamp64/www/shopp-app/.well-known"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/shopp-app/public/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: solo quiero saber como puedo instalar un certificado SSL en localhost, yo uso wamp en windows10

Comment: Yo te recomiendo que uses algunas distribucion linux y generes el SSL con certbor, que son certificados gratuitos de let´s encrypt. Bajo Windows vas a tener muchisimos problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Crear un certificado SSL para tu localhost puede ser una tarea bastante tediosa. Como estamos para ayudarnos, les dejo una guía sencilla paso a paso de como instalar un certificado SSL en tu localhost usando Wamp. Es sabido por todos los Devs que tener un servidor de desarrollo lo más idéntico posible al de producción es de vital importancia para realizar Test razonables.  Bueno, te dejo la guia definitiva:

*Observación: En algunas rutas coloco el nombre apachex.x.x, esto es porque tu versión de apache y Wamp puede ser diferente a la mía por lo que tienes que validar y estar pendiente de esta parte de los pasos.*

**Instalar OpenSSL:**

Ingresa en https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html y descarga la version correspondiente con tu sistema operativo.

Por defecto apache suele sobrescribir 2 archivos .dll muy importantes para que el certificado pueda funcionar bien, que son libay32.dll y ssleay32.dll, esto genera errores más adelante cuando estás configurando tu certificado.

Para corregirlo ve hasta la ruta

```
C:/wamp/bin/apache/apachex.x.x/bin
```

busca y confirma que estos dos archivos sean de tipo .dll y que NO pesen 0 Kb, si se cumplen una de estas condiciones, entonces dirigete a

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\phpx.x.x\ (la version de php que uses)
```

y copialos de aquí, luego vuelve y pegalos en la carpeta bin de apache. Por último ve al archivo

```
C:/wamp/scripts/config.inc.php
```

y comenta las líneas 133 y 139  y a continuación:

**Genera las llaves SSL:**

Abre la terminal y dirígete a la ruta donde se instalo openSSL la cual quedaría similar a esto: 
`C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\ (en caso que uses Window, sino sigue los pasos correspondientes en tu sistema operativo)`.

a) Ubicado en la ruta, ejecuta los siguientes comandos:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.key 2048

openssl rsa -in private.key -out private.key

openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha1 -key private.key -out certificate.crt -days 36500 -config C:/wamp/bin/apache/apachex.x.x/conf/openssl.cnf
```

b) Copia los archivos que se generaron en la ruta de la instalación de OpenSSL que deberían ser private.key y certificate.crt (estas son tus llaves para el certificado) y pegalos en

```
C:/wamp/bin/apache/apachex.x.x/conf/
```

Configurar el httpd.conf y el php.ini Ingresando en tu archivo httpd.conf y descomenta las líneas siguientes:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
```

Luego abre tu archivo php.ini y descomenta:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Revisa también que este activo en las extensiones de Php en el menú inferior derecho de Wamp.

**Configurando tu archivo httpd-ssl.conf:**

Cuando instalas y generas un certificado SSL, necesitas configurar el archivo

```
C:/wamp/bin/apache/apachex.x.x/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

para que quede así:

```
DocumentRoot “C:/wamp/www”
ServerName localhost:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog “C:/wamp/bin/apache/apachex.x.x/logs/ssl_error.log”
TransferLog “C:/wamp/bin/apache/apachex.x.x/logs/ssl_access.log”
```

*Más abajo en la línea 145:*

```
SSLCertificateFile “C:/wamp/bin/apache/apachex.x.x/conf/ssl/certificate.crt”
```

*Y en la línea 155:*

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile “C:/wamp/bin/apache/apachex.x.x/conf/ssl/private.key”
```

Debes verificar que las rutas plasmadas arriba estén correctas y que los archivos que están especificados existan (sino crealos), para que pueda funcionar. Esto me quito mucho tiempo descubrirlo y solucionarlo en su momento.

Una vez hayas creado, guardado y configurado todo como te explico, procede a probar esta configuración desde la consola en la ruta C:/wamp/bin/apache/apachex.x.x/bin/. Ejecuta el siguiente comando en la consola:

```
httpd -t
```

Chequea que la sintaxis y la configuración estén correctos.

Si después de este comando obtienes esta pantalla:

Syntax OK

Entonces todo estara bien, solo te queda reiniciar o arrancar tu server con Wamp.

Si sigues los pasos indicados y tienes cuidado que las rutas que estableces coincidan con las de tu carpeta Wamp, no deberías tener problemas y al colocar https://localhost en tu server técnicamente debes poder comenzar a correr tu propio localhost con certificado. Un error de Chrome de certificado sospechoso se obtiene como advertencia (esto es normal porque tu certificado no es reconocido como uno popular, comparado con el resto de dominios y páginas web en el mercado).

Espero haber contribuido con la comunidad con este articulo. Si tienes alguna sugerencia, duda o mejor manera de hacer las cosas, no esperes y comenta para mejorar.

Fuentes: https://medium.com/@jdevmanzo/como-crear-una-llave-ssl-para-wamp-en-localhost-8055e7116a21

Comment: Si bien tengo el servidor corriendo con SSL ya, lo que no me esta funcionando es cuando quiero acceder desde otra maquina en la misma red. Funciona la web porque el server es visible pero el certificado solo es admitido en la maquina donde esta instalado del wampserver si utilizo localhost, si coloco el nombre del equipo o su IP, muestra el sitio pero sin el certificado SSL.
Que debo modificar para que esto funcione
Gracias